# How to freeze graphs from checkpoint directory for inception-v3 model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am fine tuning inception-v3 model flowers using this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

I checkpointed the result in a directory. But in the directory I see files like these:

    `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 389908432 Mar 15 21:46 model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     72680 Mar 15 21:46 model.ckpt-0.index
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15189794 Mar 15 21:47 model.ckpt-0.meta
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135185788 Mar 15 22:36 events.out.tfevents.1489594533.f7d5defbed64
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     72680 Mar 15 22:37 model.ckpt-4999.index
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 389908432 Mar 15 22:37 model.ckpt-4999.data-00000-of-00001
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15189794 Mar 15 22:38 model.ckpt-4999.meta
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       130 Mar 15 22:49 checkpoint`

whereas I need outputs in directory similar to this:

    `-rw-r----- 1 107456 5000       223 Mar  2  2016 README.txt
    -rw-r----- 1 107456 5000        43 Mar  2  2016 checkpoint
    -rw-r----- 1 107456 5000 434903494 Mar 15  2016 model.ckpt-157585`

For that I need to do something like freezing, but freezing needs to provide output_node_names. Can anyone guide me, what will be the output_node_names for inception-v3?
Also, I need a reliable way to freeze. Is tensorflow freezer tool okay for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer eventually.

One-line answer should be to use freezer.py available in upstream Tensorflow codebase. See the example on how to use that program from tests.

You may check the following link for sample:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/morgangiraud/249505f540a5e53a48b0c1a869d370bf/raw/6cb0b4d497925517316a92f935ce5dccb6aafd17/medium-tffreeze-1.py

Comment: Just curious, what were the output node names for inception v3?

Comment: I tried the script below after fine tuning but kept getting an "AssertionError" because "Accuracy/Predictions" do not exist as output node names in Inception v3.  I have tried replacing that field with "Softmax" and anything else reasonable but it still doesn't work.  Could you please tell me how you did it?

Comment: I actually did this: https://github.com/abdasgupta/tensorflow-serving-ppc64le/blob/flowers-export/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_export.py

Comment: But if you really want to use the output nodes, please check the inception model..it is mentioned in that file

Comment: for i in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print i.name